# Chart not rendered completely when using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to print charts (JSChart) in a pdf using jsPDF. It seems like the chart image is created while the chart is not rendered completely (the data points are still on the bottom of the chart).

```
var ssvCanvas = document.querySelector('#line-chart-ssv');
var ssvCanvasImg = ssvCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
var doc = new jsPDF();
var ssvImgProps = doc.getImageProperties(ssvCanvasImg);
var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth()-20;
var ssvHeight = (ssvImgProps.height * width) / ssvImgProps.width;
doc.addImage(ssvCanvasImg, 'JPEG', 10, 40, width, ssvHeight );
```

I have no idea what could help. A wait function wasnt useful as of now.
Can somebody please help?

Comment: I found this fiddle on google: https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/kL68ey5z/ is it of any help?

Comment: Disabling the animation maybe helps

Comment: I'm not sure, if it is a animation, but when the chart is loaded the datapoints slide up from the buttom. How can I remove that?

Comment: What did the trick was animation: false. Thanks for the ideas!